# I've just installed Windows 10 on my Samsung netbook - How do I alter the screen resolution so web pages fit entirely on the screen?

Tags: windows, resolution, netbook

I've just installed Windows 10 on my Samsung netbook -  How do I alter the screen resolution so web pages fit entirely on the screen? If I go to display settings the slide bar allowing change will not move and is set at the highest setting.

Comment: Have you installed your graphics drivers? Check the Samsung website for these.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install your GPU drivers to get the complete range of resolutions in the advanced settings. This is generally updated as a part of windows update too. Install your GPU drivers and you should be good to go.

Comment: Not sure why this got a downvote

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your help. I feel i know more now, just unsure which drivers i need of Samsung - they are not very clear to me!

Comment: Refer to Samsung's website for the drivers.

Answer (score 0):

It may be that the resolution you want isn't available for the monitor/driver.  If so, just hold Ctrl and roll the mouse wheel, to zoom it to a definition you're happy with, then look through the settings of your browser, to see if there's a default zoom, and set it to the same definition.